# How do I upload an image onto a pycharm project?

Tags: image, file, pycharm

I am making a chess program for school. I have the first part of the code, but I need the images for the pieces to be in the project files. I can open my files within the project, but annoyingly cannot find a way to save them in the project.

I have had a look around, but haven't found any help on it online, making me think I must be missing something really simple. Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Let's clarify things a bit: A project in Pycharm is basically composed of a folder and all the files and subfolders contained in this folder.
Let's say your project root is a folder called `chess_game`, then if on your local machine the image files are in a subfolder `chess_game/pieces_images/`, then the images are part of the project. With that clear, could you rephrase what you mean by "save them in the project"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:
just need to upload it into the files along with the main venv library and the main program.
Simples.